# How to rename files in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

In folder i have a files with names:

```
66-1-194-111-F.tiff
66-1-194-111-F.tab
66-1-194-111-F.tfw

66-1-194-111-R.tiff
66-1-194-111-R.tab
66-1-194-111-R.tfw

66-1-194-111-G.tiff
66-1-194-111-G.tab
66-1-194-111-G.tfw
****
```

`66-1-194-111` can be changed. I want to rename this files. If last symbol in name if `F` i want to set file name `66-1-194-111-Q`. If `R` i want set file name is `66-1-194-111-W`...

How to rename files with this if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the files are named as shown,

```
ren "*-F.*" "*-Q.*"
```

Just be sure to do the rename in the adecuate order to not mix different sets of files.

For an "automated" way, you can adapt this

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    for %%a in ( "F Q" "R W" ) do for /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in (%%a) do (
        echo ren "*-%%b.*" "*-%%c.*"
    )

    endlocal
```

Note that the `ren` line is only echoed to console. If output is correct, remove `echo` to rename the files.

Comment: So for each set of files i needed to create batch file?

Comment: @KliverMax: No, just a line for each set of files, or one `for` loop over predefined variables, or .... but as said, just be sure when renaming to avoid collisions. If you rename F as Q and there are Q files, now you can not separate the two sets of files. Be sure all renames are done to something that still not exists, leaving space (letters availables) for the following renames.

Comment: @KliverMax: see updated answer. Just one way of doing it. It all depends of the real file names you have.

Comment: I puted your code in bat file. Copy bat file in folder with my files. But when i start bat file? n console i get a message that files not found.

Comment: @klivermax: test in your folder that `dir "*-f.*"` finds your files. If it does, test the updated code. I've added quotes to file masks (in this case they are not necessary, but..) and ensure that command extensions are enabled (they are enabled by default, but ...)